How can I deploy a Google Compute Engine (GCE) with consitional externalIP
as an org policy, we can't have external IPs on VMs in lower environments.
how can I conditionally have external IPs in a terraform resource block for google compute engine?

using terraform ~1.9.0  google provider ~6.8.0
pass into module
  dmz_public_ip                = terraform.workspace == "default" ? true : false


Update config with dynamics  ["prod-live"] could be any string.

resource "google_compute_instance" "vmseries" {
  name                      = "palo-vmseries-${var.availablity_zone}-${var.env}-${var.env_state}-${var.random_hex}"
  machine_type              = var.vmseries_machine_type
  project                   = var.project_id_hub_one
  zone                      = var.availablity_zone
  can_ip_forward            = true
  allow_stopping_for_update = true
  tags                      = ["gcp-family", "palo-fw"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = var.vmseries_image
      type  = "pd-standard"
    }
  }
  metadata = {
    mgmt-interface-swap                  = "enable"
    serial-port-enable                   = true
    ssh-keys                             = "admin:${var.public_key}"
    vmseries-bootstrap-gce-storagebucket = module.bootstrap.bucket_name
  }

  // nic0 - untrust nic
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.dmz.self_link
    dynamic "access_config" {
      for_each = var.dmz_public_ip ? ["prod-live"] : []
      content {}
    }
  }
  // nic1 - mgnt
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.mgnt.self_link
  }
  // nic2 - hub_one
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.hub_one.self_link
    network_ip = var.palo.fw_ip_hub_one
  }
  service_account {
    email = var.palo_sa_vm_email

    scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud.useraccounts.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write"
    ]
  }

  depends_on = [
    module.bootstrap
  ]
}


